# Shake effect kills focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The jQuery shake effect seems to kill focus of the element being shaked. For example (see http://jsfiddle.net/xSNBp/)

`$('input').focus().effect('shake', { times: 3, distance: 2 }, 30);`

kills the focus. Is this a bug? My problem is that I don't know what element is currently focused when the shake effect is triggered, so I can't refocus it. Any suggestions?

(If this is a bug, what should I do?)

Comment: Hmm are you saying regardless of what element is shaken, any element on the page loses focus?

Comment: @Loktar: Yes. Well, to be precise, I'm shaking the parent of a bunch of children. The children loose focus.

Comment: Yes it looks like an oversight rather than a bug. Raise a ticket http://bugs.jqueryui.com/

Comment: Thinking about it a shake would normally occur after an action - button press, anchor click etc so there would be no input focussed. What is your use case for this? Keypress event or similar?

Comment: @redsquare: Yeah, keypress event.

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using?  This should be fixed in 1.8.16 - see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We very recently pushed [a commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/8108ec82dbc1c203893db18aac827b93d48cfc07) to master / 1.8 to fix focus issues with some effects.  Have you tried this using the version of jQuery UI from git? Or even UI 1.8.16?

See http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7595 for the bug that called for that fix.

Here is a workaround that should fix it for you in older 1.8 code:

```
function doShake( elem, opts, duration ) {
    var active = document.activeElement;
    elem.effect( "shake", opts, duration, fixFocus );
    fixFocus();

    function fixFocus() {
       if ( active === elem[0] || $.contains( elem[0], active ) ) {
           $( active ).focus();
       }
    }
}
```

If this wasn't the problem that you were experiencing, please let us know on the bug tracker.

The reason it is happening is that when you "wrap" or append a focused element to someplace else in the DOM - it loses its focus.  So we had to add a check to the `createWrapper` and `removeWrapper` to retain the focus.

Comment: +1 its pretty awesome seeing a member of the jQueryUI team coming in to fix the issue.

Comment: Thats what happens when you link a Stack Overflow question to a bug ticket: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7681  :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following. Basically you just save the element put into focus so you can refocus it *after* the animation is complete.

```
var $focusElement;

$(":input").focus(function () {
     $focusElement = $(this);
});

// focus some random element, will be saved in the function above
$('#textTwo').focus();


$('input').effect('shake', { times: 3, distance: 2 }, 30, 
    function(){
        // Refocus the element
        $focusElement.focus();
    });
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/xSNBp/4/)**

Comment: "My problem is that I don't know what element is currently focused when the shake effect is triggered, so I can't refocus it."

Comment: @Loktar: Thanks. This is still problematic if the shake effect lasts a few seconds (or even longer!). It roughly works in my case, but is still an ugly hack.

Comment: @Randomblue I totally agree with you on its ugliness. I would definitely raise a bug like suggested above as well.

Comment: You need to do the refocus right after calling shake, (to get it after the wrap) and right after its done (to get it after the unwrap), and also check for wether or not the focus'ed element was even inside the shaking div - you'll end up where my code example is.

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it this way:

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.effect('shake', {
        times: 10,
        distance: 5
    }, 30, function() {
        el.focus()
    });
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvhER/)