# .shake() fires blur event

Tags: jquery

This is my html:

```
<div><input/></div>
```

and this is my jQuery:

```
$('input').focus();
$('input').blur(function () { console.log('BLUR!'); });
$('div').effect('shake');
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/kN7tr/

Somehow the shake effect fires the blur event. That is really annoying. Any suggestions?

*EDIT*: The following situation is similar http://jsfiddle.net/kN7tr/1/

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244558/shake-effect-kills-focus) may answer you're question

Comment: @qwertymk: Lol! I'm loosing my mind. More seriously, it seems that the problem persists even with 1.8.16

Comment: you can try unbinding the blur events, and on the callback rebinding them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, it looks like this is the culprit http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7595

This was the fix:

```
// Fixes #7595 - Elements lose focus when wrapped.
if ( element[ 0 ] === active || $.contains( element[ 0 ], active ) ) {
    $( active ).focus();
}
```

(which is on line 4425 of 1.8.16 if you're interested - the comment is misleading as it's talking about a decorator (has nothing to do with text wrapping or anything))

Fiddle has 1.8.14, which the bug was reported against.

This fix is available as in 1.8.16, which is available on  Google CDN (and obviously if you downloaded the latest)

Comment: I'd log a bug against it then, or even step through that part of the code to see if there's an unhandled edge case happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `focus` back to input after `shake` animation is complete

```
$('div').effect('shake', function(){
    $('input').focus();
});
```

Worrking **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kN7tr/4/)**

The work around for this is to attach the `blur` event inside the `shake` callback and also set the `focus` there. I really don't understand why the `focus` is going away thats why the `blur` is firing. I hope this work around helps you.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kN7tr/6/)**

```
$('input').effect('shake', function(){
    $('input').focus();
    $('input').blur(function () { console.log('BLUR!');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Randomblue - I don't see the blur happening in chrome or IE9 like you say. I do see it losing focus but when running the fiddle I don't see it logging the blur each time I hit run... this is what you described as happening correct?

Comment: @Dylan: Take a look at your console, it will say BLUR!. I'm using Chrome also.

ToShankar: Your work-around doesn't work for me, because the blur callback is defined *before* the shake effect is triggered.

Comment: This is my second demo http://jsfiddle.net/kN7tr/6/, where I am attaching the `blur` event and `focus` in the shake callback. I have also added the necessary code into my answer take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/kN7tr/7/)**

```
var $focusElement;

// Keep track of the element that was focused
$(":input").focus(function () {
     $focusElement = $(this);
});

$('input').focus();
$('input').blur(function () { console.log('BLUR!');
});

$('div').effect('shake', function(){
        // Refocus the element
        $focusElement.focus();
    });
```

Ugly hack that was also posted [Shake effect kills focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244558/shake-effect-kills-focus/7244592#7244592) where it was determined this was a bug.